# Distance/count from highest value of last 20 entries of column of data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want new column with values as the distance from max high of last 20 entries (of the column named high) 
eg. in the image the value of the new column for the last row should be 16 as max high was at the index 2020-05-07 10:00:00, similarly for the rows that follow.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)